# I am trying to dispatch an action but it does not seem to be registering

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to dispatch an action to the reducer at a certain stage but it does not seem to be working.  The showGeo() function is launched when a component mounts.  All I see in the console is an empty array which is the default state.  I have tried wrapping the code within the return block with dispatch but that does not work either.  I am a beginner to redux so any help would be appreciated.

```
export const sendAction = (user) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: GEO_SUCCESS, payload: user });
  };
};

export const showGeo = () => {
  const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('/geofire');
  const geoFire = new geofire(firebaseRef);
  let user;
  const geoQuery = geoFire.query({
    center: [37.78, -122.4],
    radius: 10 //kilometers
  });

  geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
    console.log("Bicycle shop " + key + " found at " + location + " (" + distance + " km away)");

    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + key).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      user = snapshot.val();
      sendAction(user);
      });
  });
};
```

Here is the reducer file:

```
import {
  GEO_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/types';

export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GEO_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I believe I see your issue. You're not using `dispatch` in the right function. If you're using `showGeo` within a component you must have Redux inject `dispatch` into the `showGeo` function so you can dispatch the `sendAction` function. So `showGeo` should look similar to `sendAction` like this:

```
showGeo = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    //...
    dispatch(sendAction()) // where this dispatches the action
  }
}
```

and in your component you inject `dispatch` using Redux's `mapDispatchToProps`.

I'd suggest to look over the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/) and [Thunk middlewares](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). I'd suggest going over the tutorial and browse through [Redux examples](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/Examples.html) to get a better grasp of them both.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that user is a global variable accessible by sendAction.  I will try your suggestion anyway.  Thanks

Comment: Curious.... Is there a reason why it's a global variable? You are using redux and dispatching an action to include the user within it.

Comment: No real reason for it, I changed the code to provide it as a parameter as you suggested and still the action is not updating the state with the user.